Paper used the wrong title but correct arxiv id, citation is not reflected on Google Scholar
A few years back I wrote a paper with a collaborator. We never formally published it but put it on arxiv. Later they wanted to pursue this idea further (get it into a more polished state + add some new work on top). I had other priorities but we spoke and I said that as long as my work was cited, I would be happy. They did, but unfortunately with the wrong title (an early placeholder title we used but changed when putting it on arxiv). However, the arxiv id in the citation is correct. I was hoping Google Scholar would match by the arxiv id but it doesn't seem like it. Now the citations isn't being picked up by Google Scholar (or semantic scholar).
I read this:
Citation of an article is not reflected in Google Scholar database
To address some of the points raised in that question

The citing paper is on the ACM Digital Library and has been indexed by Google Scholar
If I pick any other reference from the paper and check their citations on Google Scholar, the citing paper shows up there.

So I think the title mismatch is preventing the citations for my paper from registering.
I am curious if there is anything I can do get the citation to show up. Should I change the title on arxiv? Contact the journal? Try contacting Google Scholar (which I hear is hopeless)? Something else? I am a very junior researcher so everything counts

A hint: Don't expect Google Scholar to get much of anything right.

I suggest that you work with your co-authors on this and come to a decision on the "correct" title. Then talk to the editor of the journal to see what they suggest.
As you have found this may be a very difficult problem to solve, but get the others involved. Once that is done, try to see what Google can do for you, but I'm not hopeful.

Thank you for your suggestion. For now I changed the title on Arxiv, since it was the "least effort" path. I will give it a week or two to see if it reflects. Generally speaking, I think altering a paper once it reaches the digital library is a difficult task to alter it but certainly possible. I will contact my collaborator to see if they can change the citation if nothing comes out of the arxiv title change. Then it becomes a question of google will actually capture that small change... Hopefully this gets resolves :/

You are worrying about a single citation. It may be aggravating, and perhaps a citation you actually care about, but it's not worth your time or emotional energy. Both are better spent on creating more publications that will garner far more citations than that one.
